# Oracle DBMS_PIPE not working correctly

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a small proc as below:

```
PROCEDURE write_ToPipe ( i_key1    VARCHAR2,
                         i_value1  VARCHAR2,
                         i_key2    VARCHAR2,
                         i_value2  VARCHAR2,
                         i_key3    VARCHAR2,
                         i_value3  VARCHAR2,
                         i_key4    VARCHAR2,
                         i_value4  VARCHAR2,
                         i_key5    VARCHAR2,
                         i_value5  VARCHAR2 )
IS
   result INTEGER;

   buffer_overflow EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(buffer_overflow, -06558);
BEGIN
   -- Packing the key value paires to the local buffer
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key1);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value1);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key2);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value2);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key3);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value3);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key4);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value4);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key5);
   dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value5);
   -- sending the message to the pipe
   result := dbms_pipe.send_message(pipename => 'DB_PIPE',timeout => 5);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN buffer_overflow THEN
      -- If the buffer overflow excetion reset the local buffer and pack the messages again
      dbms_pipe.reset_buffer;
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key1);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value1);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key2);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value2);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key3);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value3);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key4);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value4);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key5);
      dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_value5);
      -- sending the message to the pipe
      result := dbms_pipe.send_message(pipename => 'DB_PIPE',timeout => 5);

END write_ToPipe;
```

I call this proc from others procs (as below).

```
proc A 
begin
  write_ToPipe( 'TEST1','TEST2', 'TEST3','TEST4','TEST5','TEST6','TEST7','TEST8','TEST9','TEST10',); 

proc B;
end 

proc b
begin
 write_ToPipe( 'SOMETEST1','SOMETEST2', 'SOMETEST3','SOMETEST4','SOMETEST5','SOMETEST6',NULL,NULL,NULL,nULL); 
end
```

there is another proc I have written to unpack the msgs and write into the flat file (not shown here)

The issue is content from proc A is getting generated into the flat file but not from proc B
After debugging I found that from proc B the write_ToPipe is called but the control comes out without throwing any exception after the following line.
dbms_pipe.pack_message(i_key1);

Can you please help to solve this?

I am using Oracle 10gR2.

Thanks and Regards,

Chandra

Comment: I don't have a 10gR2 instance to test with but it seems to work OK in 11gR2, and both messages can be received and unpacked. Maybe you can include the debug version and output that shows it silently exiting earlier; and your unpack procedure in case the problem is actually in there.

Comment: i rechecked, its exiting sliently from pack_message..

Answer (score 2):

This could be the problem with Oracle 10g. Please check with Oracle support about this.
You may also try the same program in 11g or 12c